# Scope of obseravable.subscribe

Tags: angular, observable

I'm trying to retrieve then update an object from permanent storage but cannot access the object within .subscribe. I'm very new to this and am not sure of the syntax. Can anyone please advise? How can I bring "this.socialMediaAccount" within scope so I can chain another HTTP call to perform the actual update.

```
export class SocialMediaAccountTwitterAuthorisedComponent implements OnInit {

    public errorMessage: string;
    public socialMediaAccount;

    constructor ( private socialMediaAccountService: SocialMediaAccountService, private router: Router ) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.socialMediaAccountService.findBy({'column': 'oauth_token', 'comparison_operator': 'equals', 'value': this.router.routerState.snapshot.queryParams.oauth_token })
            .subscribe(
                socialMediaAccount => this.socialMediaAccount = socialMediaAccount,
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error;

                // I need to update the object "socialMediaAccount"
                console.log( this.socialMediaAccount );
            );
    }
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your code to the callback you pass to `subscribe` which is called when data arrives:

```
export class SocialMediaAccountTwitterAuthorisedComponent implements OnInit {

    public errorMessage: string;
    public socialMediaAccount;

    constructor ( private socialMediaAccountService: SocialMediaAccountService, private router: Router ) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.socialMediaAccountService.findBy({'column': 'oauth_token', 'comparison_operator': 'equals', 'value': this.router.routerState.snapshot.queryParams.oauth_token })
            .subscribe(
                socialMediaAccount => {
                  this.socialMediaAccount = socialMediaAccount;
                  console.log( this.socialMediaAccount );
                  // I need to update the object "socialMediaAccount"
                },
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }
}
```